# Reindex price issue (value list does not match column list)

Tags: magento-1.7, price, indexing, index

Someone has used the Innoext_AdvancePricing module?
After upgreade to Magento 1.7 reindex crashes or inserts invalid data.

Crash stack trace:

```
Exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1' in lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:234
Stack trace:
#0 lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(320): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#4 lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#5 app/code/local/Innoexts/AdvancedPricing/Model/Mysql4/Catalog/Product/Indexer/Price/Configurable.php(222): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ca...')
#6 app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price/Configurable.php(50): Innoexts_AdvancedPricing_Model_Mysql4_Catalog_Product_Indexer_Price_Configurable->_applyConfigurableOption()
#7 app/code/local/Innoexts/AdvancedPricing/Model/Mysql4/Catalog/Product/Indexer/Price.php(167): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price_Configurable->reindexAll()
#8 /app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer/Abstract.php(143): Innoexts_AdvancedPricing_Model_Mysql4_Catalog_Product_Indexer_Price->reindexAll()
#9 app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(209): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->reindexAll()
#10 app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(255): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#11 shell/indexer.php(158): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#12 shell/indexer.php(198): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#13 {main}
```

Invalid data in `catalog_product_index_price` table:

```
currency is always '0.0' (should be EUR, GBP etc)
store_id is always 0
```

I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: Asking the developer of the extension might be a better place. Or provide more information - is the extension tested to work with CE 1.7 ? Did you try to reproduce the problem in a clear database?

Comment: Yes, it is tested to work with CE 1.7 and I tried with clear database. I will also try contact with developers of extension. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a mess with tables (of course because of `Column count doesn't match`).
Somehow column from `catalog_product_index_table` was deleted  or not added.

Additionally column order in method below is important.

`Innoexts_AdvancedPricing_Model_Mysql4_Catalog_Product_Indexer_Price_Configurable::_prepareFinalPriceData()`

Especially for those which  are part of primary key (`entity_id`,`customer_group_id`,`website_id`,`currency`,`store_id`).

e.g.

```
    if ($this->getVersionHelper()->isGe1700()) {
        $select->columns(array(
            'group_price'      => new Zend_Db_Expr('gp.price'), 
            'base_group_price' => new Zend_Db_Expr('gp.price'), 
        )); 
    }   
    $select->columns(array(
        'currency'      => $indexerHelper->getCurrencyExpr('cw.website_id'), 
        'store_id'      => new Zend_Db_Expr('cs.store_id'), 
    ));
```

Could be different depends how columns are ordered in table:

```
    $select->columns(array(
        'currency'      => $indexerHelper->getCurrencyExpr('cw.website_id'), 
        'store_id'      => new Zend_Db_Expr('cs.store_id'), 
    ));
    if ($this->getVersionHelper()->isGe1700()) {
        $select->columns(array(
            'group_price'      => new Zend_Db_Expr('gp.price'), 
            'base_group_price' => new Zend_Db_Expr('gp.price'), 
        )); 
    }
```